# How to find the last word in a String in Java?

Tags: java, string

How can I find the last word of a string? I am not trying to find a fixed word, in other words, I would not know what the last word is, however I want to retrieve it.

Comment: Use `String.split(" ")` and get the last item of the array?

Comment: what kind of separator between words? a white space?

Comment: I know this has been answered already but this is a good alternative : `myString.substring(myString.lastIndexOf(" ")+1).replaceAll("[.,?!]", "")`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is my code:

```
myString = myString.trim();
String[] wordList = myString.split("\\s+");
System.out.println(wordList[wordList.length-1]);
```

Comment: Your code will include ending punctuation in the sentence, which probably isn't part of the "word". See my answer for a solution.

Answer (score 5):

Providing you consider words in a sentence to be delimited by whitespace and punctuation (particularly commas, spaces, new lines, brackets, and so on), which means punctuation can appear at the end of the sentence, and you want to include non-ASCII characters in the words, then the following will find you the last word in a string *without the punctuation included*:

```
static String lastWord(String sentence) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([\\p{Alpha}]+)(?=\\p{Punct}*$)", Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(sentence);
    if (m.find()) {
        return m.group();
    }
    return ""; // or null
}
```

The regular expression uses look-ahead to find zero-or-more punctuations at the end of the string and matches the alphabetical word before it.

If you want to also allow numbers in the word, change `{Alpha}` to `{Alnum}`.

Comment: For example, this sentence returns the last word, "wørd", as expected: `lastWord("You can have it, \nthe last: wørd?!\n"`

Answer (score 4):

Read the String API for various methods you might use.

For example you could:

1. Use the `lastIndexOf(...)` method to find where the start of the word is
2. Then use the `substring(...)` method to get the word

Comment: Simple and short. The other answers are overkill.

Answer (score 0):

Use the StringTokenizer for this 
    `StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer("this is a test");`//Take any      String
        `int count = st.countTokens();`//it will count the number of token in that particular String

```
String[] myStringArray = new String[count];
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        `myStringArray[i] = st.nextToken();`//insert the words/Tken in to the string array
    }
    `System.out.println("Last Word is--" +  myStringArray[myStringArray.length - 1])`;//get the last words of the given String
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    System.out.println("enter the string");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String instr = input.nextLine();
    instr = instr.trim();
    int index = instr.lastIndexOf(" ");
    int l = instr.length();
    System.out.println(l);
    String lastStr = instr.substring(index+1,l);
    System.out.println("last string .."+lastStr);
```